# How to change kendo TreeMap theme

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I have a Kendo UI TreeMap using the razor syntax:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeMap()
    .Name("treeMap")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("_PopulationUSA", "TreeMap"))
        .Model(m => m.Children("Items")))
    .ValueField("Value")
    .TextField("Name")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px" })
)
```

How can I change the default theme to a custom theme?

Comment: You can not easily add it as, @(Html.Kendo().TreeMap().Theme("blueOpal")

Answer (score 0):

`.Theme("BlueOpal")` should work, perhaps you just spelled "BlueOpal" wrong?

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeMap()
    .Name("treeMap")
    .Theme("BlueOpal")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("_PopulationUSA", "TreeMap"))
        .Model(m => m.Children("Items")))
    .ValueField("Value")
    .TextField("Name")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px" })
)
```